# Hide the slider image without deleting

Tags: html, css

Try to hide the slider background image in mobile screen:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
.home #mainSliderWrapper {
    background-image: none;
}
.stlye {
    background-image: none;
}
.img--holder {
    background-image:none;
}
}
```

It wasn't working, can anyone help me ? The site is: https://uraniamedicalcenter.hu
The id is mainSliderWrapper.
Am i using wrong the class and the id ?

trying these too:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
.home #mainSliderWrapper {
    background: none !important;
}
 #mainSliderWrapper #mainSlider .slide .img--holder {
    background-image:none;
}
#mainSlider .slide .img--holder {
    background-image:none;
}
#mainSlider .img--holder{
    background-image: none;
}
}
```

won't working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your HTML for the slider as well. If you fix that link, this question will become useless for future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are using the `!important` on your background image style so you will also have to use `!important` on your mobile styles. It is bad practice to put `!important` on every style... then it loses its purpose. I recommend removing `!important` altogether

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
@media (max-width:800px) and (min-width: 0px)
And use background, no background-image because in your code it's background

Answer (score 0):

There is the CSS rule

```
.home #mainSliderWrapper{
  background: 'imageURL' !important;
}
```

that you have to overwrite with your !important custom rule:

```
$('.home #mainSliderWrapper').css('{ background: none !important }');
```